# Is it possible to run different builds with a single Gatsby project?

Tags: gatsby

I need to build a generic landing page in which I’ll have three different builds for three different customers. The landing page is almost identical to each other, the differences are some background images and some customer specific texts/data in the page.

I think that it could be done by using some kind of dynamic parameters within the build process, maybe selecting a different config on build time, but I could not find a way to do that. I would like to know if this can be done with Gatsby or if you have any resources I could use it to accomplish that.

Thanks

Comment: You can use environment variables. Check here : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/

Comment: It could be useful, but due to Gatsby nature, it is not possible to pass parameters to graphql to dynamically fetch images according to the customer in the environment variable.

Comment: Why not just use Optimizely or another A/B testing suite? They are designed for just this use case.